# How render Angular 10 project Microfront

Tags: angular, angular-material, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I have an existing Angular 10 project I want use it as a microFrontEnd in another shell application .I tried to use angular federation but it seems not possible.
Please how can i do it and what are the steps?
Thank  you

Answer (score 0):

You can load different version of angular or even different technology inside your shell application using @angular-architects/module-federation-tools package.

You can use the WebComponentWrapperOptions from the above package and render your angular 10 inside your shell application.

for more clarity please refer this article. https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/main/libs/mf-tools/tutorial/index.md